# Distinguish between Clang CL and MSVC CL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, clang-cl

There is CLang-CL which is a drop-in replacement for MSVC's CL.

Does anyone know how to distinguish if my code is currently compiled by clang-cl or msvc's cl? Without passing any extra defined macros on command line.

Using

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
//.....
#endif
```

doesn't work, both compilers define _MSC_VER.

Also in regular CLang on Linux (Windows too) it was possible to do `clang -dM -E - < /dev/null` which dumps all defined macros. But clang-cl and msvc-cl both don't have such option to dump all defined macros as far as I know, so I don't know of a way to see a difference in list of defined macros for both compilers to figure out which macro to use to distinguish between these compilers.

Comment: Clarify if the question is about C or C++. Answers will be wildly different depending on language.

Comment: @Lundin Removed C tag, more interested in C++ solutions. Also if you know can you tell how to solve my task in C?

Comment: What about `__clang__`?

Comment: In C there's `#ifdef __STDC__` which I don't think MS defines, since they don't follow standard C.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! `__clang__` macro works! Can you post it as an answer so I accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro you're looking for is `__clang__`.

Note that the regular Clang (not only Clang-CL) also defines it, so you want to check for both `__clang__` and `_MSC_VER` at the same time.